# Error en la peticion web service soap en android

Tags: android

Estoy usando un web service SOAP, pero a la hora de hacer la petición, no la hace.

Código:

```
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Webservice extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitNetwork().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        setContentView(R.layout.webservice);
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("nombre", "v");
        System.out.println("Nombre: "+request);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope sobre = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        sobre.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try{
            System.out.println("Evelopen: "+sobre);
            transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION, sobre);
            if (transporte!=null) {
                System.out.println("Trasporte SI");
            }
            else{System.out.println("Error en el Trasporte");}
            SoapPrimitive resultado = (SoapPrimitive) sobre.getResponse();
            Log.i("Resultado", resultado.toString());
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error1 "+e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (XmlPullParserException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error2 "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Con estos valores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado que me sale es esto:

```
I/System.out: Nombre: nombre{nombre=v; }
I/System.out: Evelopen: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope@421aed0
I/System.out: Trasporte SI
I/Resultado: Holanull
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab2ea1d0
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xa27a9d80 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xad9f9cf0
```

Mi web service es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: final String NAMESPACE = "http://datos/";
    final String URL = "http://192.168.1.74:7001/Ejemplo-Datos-context-root/HolaPort?xsd=1";
    final String METHOD_NAME = "nombre";
    final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://consultas/nombre";